# @EnableJpaRepositories annotation disables data.sql initialization script

Tags: database, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

My Spring Boot (v2.3.4) based application uses my custom library containing core entities and business logic. To use entities and repositories from this library I had to use `@EnableJpaRepositories` and `@EntityScan` annotations with proper packages provided.

I also wanted to initialize database with some required data (let's say the configuration) during application startup. I found that Spring Boot allows to use `data.sql` or `data-${platform}.sql` files to achieve that.

Long story short when using `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation the `data.sql` script is not executed.

I did some digging in the code and found that when `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation is not used then `entityManagerFactory` bean is of `org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` type. This bean uses `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher` bean post processor, which fires `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceSchemaCreatedEvent` event indicating the schema has been created. Class, which listens for this event is `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker`. This listener invokes `initSchema()` method from `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer` class. This method is responsible for whole initialization using `data.sql` script.

It looks like setting `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation creates instance of different class for `entityManagerFactory` bean, which does not support this simple initialization.

My basic question is then how to make it all work with `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation. I can always use Hibernate's `import.sql` file (which works fine) but I'm also trying to understand what exactly is going on under the hood I how can I control it.

**UPDATE 1** 28.09.2021

I did further investigation and `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation does not change the instance type of `entityManagerFactory` but it causes silent exception (?) when creating `org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration` bean (during creation of `org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAsyncAnnotationProcessor` bean). It looks like everything is related to `@EnableAsync` annotation, which I'm also using but didn't know it might be related. But it is - removing it makes the initialization work even with `@EnableJpaRepositories`.

**UPDATE 2** 28.09.2021

I've found full explanation for my issue. There are 4 conditions, which must be met to reproduce the issue:

- `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation in application configuration
- `@EnableAsync` annotation in application configuration
- Configuration implements `AsyncConfigurer` interface
- Autowired any `JpaRepository` repository or any other bean which injects repository

Enabling asynchronous execution and implementing `AsyncConfigurer` makes the whole configuration to be instantiated before regular beans. Because Spring has to inject repository, it needs to instantiate `entityManagerFactory` bean too. Spring prints then`INFO` level logs like below:

```
Bean 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' of type [org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
```

One of not eligible `BeanPostProcessors` is `DataSourceInitializedPublisher` responsible for firing `DataSourceSchemaCreatedEvent` event. Without that event, `data-${platform}.sql` script won't be processed at all.

I'm not sure what is the role of `@EnableJpaRepositories` in that process but without it the problem does not occur.

**Example**

Minimal code to reproduce the issue (`data.sql` located in `src/main/resources`):

```java
@Entity
public FileStore {
    ...
}

public interface FileStoreRepository extends extends JpaRepository<FileStore, Long> {
}

@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class Configuration implements AsyncConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    private FileStoreRepository fileStoreRepository;

    ...
}
```

**Solutions**

There are two solutions I'm aware of:

- Move `AsyncConfigurer` along with its overrided methods and `@EnableAsync` annotation to separate configuration class
- Use `@Lazy` annotation on autowired bean like below:

```
@Lazy
@Autowired
private FileStoreRepository fileStoreRepository;
```

Similar problem was pointed by [@Allen D. Ball](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69353314/enablejparepositories-annotation-disables-data-sql-initialization-script#comment122602836_69364791) and can be checked [there](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15440).

Answer (score 0):

This behavior had changed.

Take a look at the
[how-to guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization).

Add:

```
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization: true
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. I'm using Spring Boot v2.3.4 while the change you described was intruduced around v2.5. My latest findings related issue to `@EnableAsync` annotation. I found that when `@EnableAsync` is used, beans created in configuration prints `(...)is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors(...)` message and this might be related to the fact that I'm also implementing `AsyncConfigurer` interface. I found it is a special interface instantiated before regular beans. I think it might be related. I'm trying to confirm that.

Comment: Good find. I did a little more research and found this [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15440) which was closed as not a bug.  The conclusion is to annotate the beans as `@Lazy`.  HTH